# Why does re-borrowing only work on de-referenced pointers?

Tags: rust, borrowing

This question and code are adapted from [Why does creating a mutable reference to a dereferenced mutable reference work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095523/why-does-creating-a-mutable-reference-to-a-dereferenced-mutable-reference-work). The answers there explained re-borrowing but not the reasons for the conventions around it.

The two calls to `test` below seem equivalent, why does only the first one work?

```
fn main() {
    let mut string = String::new();
    let ref_string = &mut string;

    // Compiles
    test(&mut *ref_string);

    // Doesn't compile
    test(&mut string);
}

fn test(s: &mut String) {
    s.push('t');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only allowed to have a single mutable reference to a value at a time. When you mutably reborrow as an argument, it's *trivial* for the compiler to see that you aren't going to be using `ref_string` at the same time and thus the code is safe.

My mental image is that there's a "chain of custody" for the mutability. `ref_string` is the holder and can temporarily give that up to the temporary created by `&mut *ref_string`. When that goes out of scope, the mutability is returned to it. It's as if the code were:

```
{
    let x = &mut *ref_string;
    test(x);
}
```

However, when you try to "go around" and get the mutable reference, you are ignoring the chain of custody. The compiler stops you because it cannot *trivially* see that it is safe.

---

Of note is that [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423) improves the original situation. When the MIR-based borrow checker is enabled, the compiler can see that `ref_string` is no longer in use by the time the second call to `test` happens, thus it's safe for the exclusive access to be transferred there.