# Why does the compiler error complain about multiple mutable references not dangling reference?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to understand what exactly happens when functions reborrow  mutable references.

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = String::new();
    let mut b = String::new();
    let aa = &mut a;
    let c = my_fun(aa, &mut b);
    let d = &mut a;
    println!("{}", c);
}
                
fn my_fun<'b>(x: &'b mut String, y: &'b mut String) -> &'b mut String { y }
```

From my understanding the `my_fun`  reborrows `aa` as `&*aa` whose scope would be the `my_fun`. But due to the lifetime bound I created in the function signature the reborrow should live at least as long as `&mut b` exist. So the `println` force the reborrow to live until it.

Shouldn't this be throwing an error of use after free because the anonymous reborrow has only scope inside `my_fun`? Outside of this function this reference shouldn't be valid.

But the error I get is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `a` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:7:13
  |
5 |     let aa= &mut a;
  |             ------ first mutable borrow occurs here
6 |     let c = my_fun(aa, &mut b);
7 |     let d = &mut a;
  |             ^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
8 |     println!("{}", c);
  |                    - first borrow later used
```

which would have made sense if the mutable reference was merely copied instead of reborrowed inside the function.

Comment: but https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=74c1b980a6e14201079d1f18a49e7c16 I don't get what block you, you declare "as long as the return of my_fun live, the two argument must live"

Comment: Ya I made those bounds to better understand whats going on behind reborrows than to make it work. So my question essentially is , how can a reborrow be "alive" outside its scope which is the function here.

Comment: cause you use c that borrow aa after your reborrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my understanding the `my_fun` reborrows `aa` as `&*aa` whose scope would be the `my_fun`.

It's not quite that.

Let's backtrack a bit: why reborrowing?

There is a fundamental difference between `&T` and `&mut T`: `&T` is `Copy`, whereas `&mut T` is not even `Clone`. The result is that `&mut T` can only be *moved* and therefore a call such as:

```
let x: &mut T = /*...*/;
func(x);
```

Would result in `x` being unusable after the call. The work-around would then be to introduce a temporary:

```
let x: &mut T = /*...*/;
let tmp = &mut *x;
func(tmp);
```

This temporary would re-borrow the pointee of `x`, and be consumed by `func`.

And... that's *re-borrowing*! The compiler has this "temporary" creation built-in purely for ergonomics!

With that in mind, let's go back to:

> From my understanding the `my_fun` reborrows `aa` as `&*aa` whose scope would be the `my_fun`.

Lifetimes are generally more a *range* than a *point*, and this is true here.

The lifetime of `tmp` in my example above is constrained in 2 ways:

- It cannot be greater than that of `x`.
- It cannot be less than that of `func`.

Which is another way of saying that it can be **anything** in between those bounds.

Comment: Thanks. I had the model in which the reborrow was defined inside the function. That caused the confusion of lifetime of the temporary reference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're overthinking "reborrowing" here.

The lifetime requirements you applied say that the thing being referenced by the return value will have at least the lifetime of the things being referenced by the parameters. That's true (and if it weren't provably true, this wouldn't compile). So there is no dangling reference possible.

There isn't a separate "reborrowed" reference. Borrowing is bookkeeping inside the compiler to keep track of lifetimes. There is no `let x = &*aa` step that actually occurs or is even particularly implied. This isn't like reference counting where memory actually changes at runtime.

Inside of `my_fun`, `y` is a reference that's scoped to the function. But the *return value* is scoped to the caller. (Functions would be impossible to use if this weren't true, having nothing to do with `&mut`.)